# Pymongo transfer unicode to datetime in find query

Tags: mongodb, datetime, pymongo

Im trying to find data added with 2 dates. And my query is as below:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)
for data in db.data1.find({(datetime.strptime("d", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')): {"$gt" : dt, "$lt" : datetime.now()}}):
```

But I get ValueError: time data 'd' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'

And 'd' value is as below:

```
 "d" : "2017-01-08T12:25:41.570746",
```

I'm not getting whats wrong in my query.

I know this is duplicate, but I have tried all methods it dint work!

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this is a string:

```
"d"
```

What you want is a reference to a variable:

```
d
```

Like so:

```
for data in db.data1.find({(datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')): {"$gt" : dt, "$lt" : datetime.now()}}):
```

Comment: @Jesse 'd' is feild in data1 collection from mongodb. So i want to query mongodb. I just specified what iis the 'd' value here or how it looks like.